# Laravel send multiple posts but save only the last one to database

Tags: php, html, database, laravel, post

In Laravel I'm developing a web app where users will answer true or false questions on separate pages. On each page I'd like to somehow save their answer and in the end save the results to the database.

I could make a POST form on each page which would increment 'points' field in the database if the answer was correct. But that would require many accesses to the database by each user as answers would be saved on each page. Is there a way to store their points to a variable on the server and then save that variable to the database in the end?

I've thought of saving points to session but that wouldn't be safe as sessions can be modified by users.

Right now my controller only returns the intro page.

```
class QuizController extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        return view("quiz.pages.1");
    }

    public function addPoint() {
        $points++;
    }

    public function getPoints() {
        return $points;
    }
}
```

And a route to redirect to the next pages.

```
Route::get('quiz/{page}', function($page) {
    return View::make('quiz.pages.' . $page);
});
```

Comment: Where is your save method ? Unclear what you are asking for me

Comment: I don't understand why you consider storing points in the session unsafe. Sessions are stored on the server, not on the client. It is quite unlikely that an user will modify a session to their advantage.

Comment: You could use sessions (it can be modified only by usesrs that have access to your server), or store points in fast cache like [redis](https://redis.io/).

Comment: @KIKOSoftware and marv255 You are correct. I got confused between server side sessions and HTML5's sessionStorage. I will solve the problem using server side sessions. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The way i would achieve this in my opinion is to send hidden inputs to your pages and not save() them until the end. So it would look something like this.

```
firstpage.blade.php

<input type="text" name="yourinputname">
```

So then you can pass this input from your controller to the next page without saving it. Something like:

```
public function index(Request $request) {

    $yourVariablename = new YourModelName;
    $yourVariableName->yourDatabaseColumnName = $request->input('yourinputname');

    return view("quiz.pages.1", [
      'anyName' => $yourVariableName
    ]);
}
```

Notice there is no save() on the controller yet because we want to save it at the end so we just store it. From this points onward you can just do something like this in the next pages until you get to the point where you want to save.

```
anotherpage.blade.php

<input type="hidden" name="yourinputname">
```

When you gather all the data, just match them with your database columns and then save() it. I hope it solves your problem.